# Login Openshift with GitHub

Tags: github, openshift

OpenShift has only creates github, but when I try rhc setup from terminal, do not know what username and password. I tried with the user and password github, but rejects it.
What would be the username and password ?.

thanks

Comment: Are you talking about OpenShift 3, the new version based on Kubernetes? The online preview environment for this uses GitHub for login, but ``rhc`` is for the older OpenShift 2 and not this version. The client for OpenShift 3 is ``oc``. Once you are logged into the web console for OpenShift 3, you can find a link to download ``oc`` client by going to Help->Command Line Tools menu. Help is the ? in circle top right in web console.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use OC, then go to https://console.preview.openshift.com/console/command-line.
There you will find a command line with a token to authenticate.
The rhc do not work with github authentication as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

I'll repeat what others have said, but with screenshots:
Once you're logged in to the web interface, click the (?) icon in the top bar, select Command Line Tools entry:

[image: screenshot of ? menu -> Command Line Tools]

This will show a page which includes exact `oc login` options you need to login.  Note you need to use the "copy to clipboard" button to actually get the token:

[image: screenshot of oc login line, copy to clipboard button]

Answer (score 0):

You need to login with your GitHub account, authorize the application, wait a while until an email comes to your GitHub email address, then login to GitHub again following the steps in the email. I did this and it worked.

Comment: Yes, I did that and maybe already create a project web console, but when I want to login by RHC, do not know which is user and pasword, since it rejects the user and pasword me github

Comment: Thanks @XavCo7, the solution given by Graham Dumpleton was perferct for me.